# How to create a continuously moving rectangle using the arrow keys to develop snake?

Tags: python

I'm  trying to create snake in python using pygame, but I can not figure out how to get the head of the snake to continuously move with the press of one key.

I've tried using a while loop but that only caused the program to freeze.

```
run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and snake_x > 0:
        snake_x -= snake_vel
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and snake_x < 500 - snake_vel:
        snake_x += snake_vel
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and snake_y < 500 - snake_vel:
        snake_y += snake_vel
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and snake_y > 0:
        snake_y -= snake_vel

    canvas.fill((0, 0, 0))
    snake = pygame.draw.rect(canvas, (0, 255, 0), (snake_x, snake_y, snake_width, snake_height))
    pygame.display.update()
```

so far the snake head is only moving while holding down one of the arrow keys, but i would like it to move continuously with the press of one arrow key until another one is pressed

Comment: use a variable - if a key is pressed set the variable that records direction. On each loop if no key pressed keep going in the variables direction.